# Task Scheduler Event Trigger When It Contains Text

Tags: xml, events, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a task scheduler event that triggers when our application runs into an exception. However, I only want it to look for a certain string of text. So is there a way to craft an XML event filter that will look for part of some text using a wildcard or contains? I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">
                 *[EventData[Data and (Data='*non-base 64 character*')]]
               </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly what you were looking for, but I had a similar requirement and I could resolve it by filtering the actual XML behind the text. When you have a look at the details tab you'll probably see the "raw" data behind the text (in the XML view), what you could use instead of a contains filter.

I wanted to filter for a event with the text:
"Volume R: (\Device\HarddiskVolume42) is healthy.  No action is needed."
So I was looking for something like "*Volume R:*" AND "*healthy*".
But when having a closer look aht the XML view, I figured out that the drive name is actually stored in an own data. So my final filter was:

```
    <QueryList>
      <Query Id="0" Path="System">
        <Select Path="System">
        *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs']]]
        and
        *[System[(EventID='98')]]
        and
        *[EventData[Data[@Name='DriveName'] and (Data='R:')]]
        and
        *[EventData[Data[@Name='CorruptionActionState'] and (Data='0')]]
        </Select>
      </Query>
    </QueryList>
```

To test the query you can always create a custom view in the event viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, based on [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/827016/how-to-filter-windows-event-log-with-wildcard), it seems this isn't possible. I've spent a good hour searching for a way and trying different things and couldn't get anything to work, so even though it looks like there's no actual solution I'm posting here because this question came up much earlier than that one did in my searching (I found it once I started using "xpath" in my searches), so hopefully it'll save others some time.